# JMockit: Mocked apis are getting reverted after sometime

Tags: java, bytecode, jit, jmockit, java-bytecode-asm

I am using JMockit to mock System.currentMillis().
Few invocations returning mocked time but after sometime, it starts returning original time.
When I run the same after disabling the JIT, it runs perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the JIT optimizer in the JVM does not check for redefined methods (redefinition is done through a different subsystem in the JVM). So, eventually the JVM decides to optimize the code containing the call to `System.currentTimeMillis()`, inlining the call to the `native` Java method so that it starts executing the actual native method directly. At this point, the optimizer should check if `currentTimeMillis()` is currently redefined or not, and abandon the inlining in case it is redefined. But, unfortunately, the JDK engineers failed to account for this possibility.

If you really need to invoke a mocked `System.currentTimeMillis()` too many times, the only workaround is indeed to run with `-Xint` (which is not such a bad idea, as it usually reduces the total execution time of the test run).

Comment: Interesting. Is it specific to currentTimeMillis()? Otherwise entire Instrumentation will go for a toss and it will be probabilistic feature. @Rogerio

Comment: It only affects native methods like `currentTimeMillis()`.

Comment: I wouldn’t be surprised if it applies to all [*intrinsic* methods](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/PerformanceTechniques#PerformanceTechniques-Intrinsics), regardless of whether they have a `native` or pure Java implementation. These methods are expected to have a well defined semantic. E.g. `Math.sqrt` is not `native` but I guess, mocking it will fail as well once the optimizer kicks in…

Comment: @Holger It's possible, but so far I only observed this issue with `System.currentTimeMillis()` and `System.nanoTime()`.

Comment: Is it specific to JMokit? Because when we did the same exercise with PowerMock, we didn't see any issues like this.

Comment: @Sainath Sarma: I don’t know any internals, but there is a workaround; just instrument the caller instead of the special method, redirecting the invocation at the call site. Maybe PowerMock does that.

Comment: @Holger Yes, that's exactly what PowerMock does: to mock "system" (JRE) classes like `java.lang.System`, it creates a modified copy of the caller class (which needs to be specified with `@PrepareForTest`).

Answer (score 3):

You obviously have an important dependency to the current time inside one or more of your components. In this case you should express this dependency with an interface:

```
public interface TimeService {
    long currentTimeMillis();
}
```

In your real code you have an implementation that uses the `System` method:

```
public final SystemTimeService implements TimeService {
    @Override
    public long currentTimeMillis() {
        return System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
```

Note, with Java 8 you can reduce some code to express it more clearly (thanks @Holger):

```
public interface TimeService {
    static final DEFAULT = System::currentTimeMillis;
    long currentTimeMillis();
}
```

Your classes that depend on this time service should look like that:

```
public final ClassThatDependsOnTimeService {
    private final TimeService timeService;

    public ClassThatDependsOnTimeService(TimeService timeService) {
        this.timeService = timeService;
    }

    // other features omitted
}
```

Now they can be fed with

```
TimeService timeService = new SystemTimeService();
ClassThatDependsOnTimeService someObject = new ClassThatDependsOnTimeService(timeService);
```

or (Java 8):

```
ClassThatDependsOnTimeService someObject = new ClassThatDependsOnTimeService(TimeService.DEFAULT);
```

or with any dependency injection framework or whatever.

In your tests you do not mock the method `System.currentTimeMillis` but you mock the interface `TimeService` and inject the mock into the depending classes.

Comment: That’s a good advice. In Java 8, you can also add a `TimeService DEFAULT=System::currentTimeMillis;` to the `interface`, reducing the code required for the abstraction.